# How do the tries work that are used in the mmo object format's symbol tables?

Tags: trie, object-files, mmix

I try to understand, how the `mmo` object file format works, which is used for Don Knuth's educational `MMIX` architecture. I have not bought *MMIXware*, so I have to guess most of the details from the literate source files of the assembler and simulator.

The object format uses a special *ternary search trie* for storing the symbol table. At a look at the code, I don't quite understand how it works. Can somebody please explain me some details? Especially about how the tree is serialized.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think I can do much better than the explanation found [here](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/binutils/bfd_209.html).

Comment: Hm... I asked for a *detailed* explanation, but since you are the only one to answer my question and I don't want my 100 points wasted, you get the bounty. The page you link to makes a better explanation about the codes themself, but I still kind of don't understand how those tries work.